# Can we hide/unhide one or more components in a single UIPickerview?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have a `UIPickerview` with 2 components . Now I would like to know if it is possible to hide/unhide one component on a button click . Is it possible ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. When the button is clicked, tell the picker to `reloadAllComponents` and then in the datasource methods return a different number of components (ie one 1 instead of 2).

You'll need to store the hiding state in a BOOL so that you know what to return in the datasource methods.